# How can `standardize=TRUE` and `intercept=FALSE` be available at the same time in the function `glmnet`?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, glmnet

`glmnet` is a widely-used R package for generalized linear regression. Among the arguments passed to the main function `glmnet::glmnet()`, the `standardize` controls whether the feature matrix is standardized before fitting, and the `intercept` determines whether an intercept is included in the linear model.

The thing is, `glmnet` allows the model to standardize the feature and fit with no intercept at the same time, which is confusing to me. Suppose that there is a feature $X$ standardized as $\tilde{X}=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$, and $\tilde\beta$ is the estimated coefficient in front of $\tilde X$. When we recover the coefficient $\beta = \tilde\beta/\sigma$ for the unstandardized feature, a constant $-\tilde\beta\mu/\sigma$ is pulled out and added to the intercept. As a side result, an intercept is almost inevitable.

As the core algorithm of `glmnet` is written in Fortran, it is hard for me myself to look into its implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standardisation and intercept code isn't in the Fortran, it's in `glmnet/R/glmnetFlex.R`

Examining the code confirms that the `intercept` argument is about centering `x` and the `standardize` argument is about scaling `x` to unit variance, so they really are independent choices.

That is, `standardize` is about the units of the coefficients and `intercept` is about the choice of "zero" point for the sparsity.

```
if (intercept) {
        xm <- meansd$mean
    } else {
        xm <- rep(0.0, times = nvars)
    }
if (standardize) {
        xs <- meansd$sd
    } else {
        xs <- rep(1.0, times = nvars)
    }
```